# Laser Color Printer Recommendation

Tags: printer

I want some printer recommendation for the below specifications

1. Color Laser
2. Multifunction - Printer, Fax, Scan, Copy
3. Separate Ink Toners
4. Paper Size: I want 'A3'. But I searched a lot. Laser printers not apt with 'A3' Papers. So it should apt with A4, Letter, Legal, Envelopes, etc.
5. Two Sided Printing
6. 10 People shared Office Printer connected via Ethernet.
7. Able to connect to Linux Machines.
8. 15 to 25 ppm.
9. Duplex Scan and Copy optional.
10. Budget only before $1000. If A3 is not fit with $1000 printer, then Letter and Legal could be the max paper size.

Answer (score 1):

The printer Sharp MX-5140N has all your mentioned specifications.

BUT: it is an printer for big offices, if you look for a printer at home, this is not for you.

Additionally it might be best, if you rent this printer with a SLA.